# How to access iPad device directories via Mac Terminal

Tags: ios, terminal

I am quite new in iPad dev. It would be of great help if following question is answered  :
How to access iPad device directories via Mac Terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can't access directories in device, but you can in the simulator.
Path to iPhone Simulator directories is:

```
/Users/user_name/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/
```

Maybe it is possible when you jailbrake your device but I never did it.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution: jailbreak it, and install `netatalk` on it.

Comment: Bad idea, how can you develop on a jailbreaked device?

Comment: I’ve always been doing this and developing the official way. Everyone does here at my company, and we’ve never experienced any problem.